# Model binding run before auth middleware

Tags: laravel, model-binding, laravel-middleware

I want to ask how can you run the auth middleware before the model binding? Currently in my 5.7 application, model binding is run before the auth. I tried creating a middlwaregroup in kernel.php as follows:

```
        'api' => [
        'throttle:10,1',
        'jwt.middleware',
        'bindings',
    ],
```

But still the model binding is run before the auth. Also I tried to change the order of the two middlewares in my route but nothing changed.

Comment: what are you using for your authentication middleware? as the middleware priorities have it defined for the default auth middleware to run before the binding middleware, you can see this in the `$middlewarePriority` array in the Kernel

Comment: I'm using custom auth controller using JWT

Comment: then that isn't the 'auth' middleware ... so you will have to add to the `$middlewarePriority` array to add the class for that middleware, what ever `jwt.middleware` is, to be before the bindings middleware

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#sorting-middleware

```
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you use explicit bindings, they may run before the auth middleware. In that case, you can use `Auth::authenticate()` to throw an `AuthenticationException` which laravel will transform into a redirect to the login page.

```php
Route::bind('user_post', fn ($id) => Auth::authenticate()->posts()->findOrFail($id));
```

```php
Route::get('posts/{user_post}', ...);
```